# Mysql CakePHP 2.0

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I want to make a MySQL query in CakePHP 2.0 which looks like this:

```
select p.ciname HOSTNAME
    ,a.status HPSA
    ,m.status SM9
    ,p.status LDAP 
from hpsas a, hpsms m, ldaps p 
where (p.ciname = a.ciname) 
and (p.ciname = m.ciname) 
order by p.ciname;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The model looks like this:                                         <?php
class Test extends AppModel {
public  $useTable = 'ldaps';
}

Answer (score 0):

You can make arbitrary SQL queries in CakePHP using the `Model.query()` method. For example, in a controller:

```
$sql = ...your sql here...
$results = $this->ModelName->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to make this query using cake ORM I think this would be a step in that direction:

```
$options = array();
$options['fields'] => array('p.ciname AS HOSTNAME', 'a.status AS HPSA', 'm.status AS SM9', 'p.status AS LDAP');
$options['joins'][] => array('table' => 'hpsas', 'alias' => 'a', 'conditions' => array('p.ciname = a.ciname'));
$options['joins'][] => array('table' => 'hpsms', 'alias' => 'm', 'conditions' => array('p.ciname = m.ciname'));

$result = $this->Test->find('all', $options);
```

Those fields and table names don't comply with cake convention, understandable if you are migrating or integrating your project. If you are starting now, you might want to rename them.

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions